# What is the cosine of angle of intersection of following functions?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

1st Function: $\displaystyle 3^{x-1}\log x$

2nd Function: $\displaystyle x^x-1$

How to find the cosine of angle of intersection of these two curves? Their $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ are not really neat, and can't be converted to cosine conveniently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the point of intersections of both curves, and then, find a tangent vector of both curves at the point of intersection. The angle $\theta$ between two vectors $e_{1}$ and $e_{2}$ satisfies, $\cos \theta =\frac{e_{1} \cdot e_{2}}{\Vert e_{1} \Vert \Vert e_{2}\Vert}$

Comment: How do you find the point of intersection without guessing?

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{d}{dx} 3^{x-1}\log(x)=\frac{3^{x-1}(x\log(3) \log(x)+1)}{x}$

$\frac{d}{dx} x^x-1 = x^x(\log(x)+1)$

The two functions meet at $x=1$, therefore, the slope of function 1 is $1$ and the slope of function 2 is $1$.  Since they have the same slope, the cosine of the angle between them equals 1 as well.

Comment: A small edit! Hope you won't mind!

Comment: @mich95 not at all :) thx.