# Plotting the set of complex numbers that satisfy an inequality

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions

I am trying to understand how to plot the set on the complex plane that satisfies $$\mid 1 + z + z^2|<4$$ where $z \in \mathbb{C}$.  I have tried to use $z = a+bi$ and substitute in to the inequality, but I am left with imaginary numbers that I do not know how to interpret.  Is there anyway to visualize this inequality graphically on the complex plane?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the roots of $z^2+z+1$ are $-\frac12\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2i$. So$$\lvert z^2+z+1\rvert<4\iff\left\lvert z-\left(-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)\right\rvert\times\left\lvert z-\left(-\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)\right\rvert<4.$$Therefore, you have the set of those points $z\in\mathbb C$ such that the product of their distances to $-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i$ and to $-\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2i$ is smaller that $4$. So, you get the region of $\mathbb C$ bounded by a [Cassini oval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval):

[image]

Comment: I didn't know this characterization $MF_1\cdot MF_2=k$ as oval. Are there any other interesting ones besides ellipse: $MF_1+MF_2=k$, hyperbola: $MF_1-MF_2=k$ and Apolonius circle $\frac{MF_1}{MF_2}=k$ ?

Comment: I suggest that you read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oval).

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've seen the smart way to do this, let's do it the dumb way! (Well, it always works a charm for me.)

This is written for Python 3.4.0 and matplotlib 2.1.1. (Yes, my computer is very old.)

`from random import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 10000
M = 3.0
X = []
Y = []
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.xlim(-3,3)
plt.ylim(-3,3)
for count in range(N):
    x = M*(2*random() - 1)
    y = M*(2*random() - 1)
    z = x + y*1j
    if abs(z**2 + z + 1) < 4:
        X.append(x)
        Y.append(y)
plt.scatter(X, Y, s=1, c='k')
plt.show()`

[image: Really dumb plot.]

(I'll get me coat.)

Comment: Funny, this is the same idea I did in MATLAB.  Gave me the same result, I was curious how to derive the set mathematically.

Comment: I bet you were too ashamed to mention it! I have no shame. :)

Comment: Seriously, though: when working on another problem ([this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3392025) one), I have found it a terrible temptation to spend too much time time drawing pretty pictures with matplotlib, and not enough time actually trying to prove things. So I do have some shame.